# add multiple objects to javascript array - from one single DataBase string value - WITHOUT using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Thanks for taking a look : )

I know that I can add multiple objects at once in a javascript array like this:

```
<script>

    var myCarsArray = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];

    alert("The second element in my array = "+myCarsArray[1]);

</script>
```

This alerts 'The second element in my array = Volvo'.

I want to simply store the array values in the database as a string - 
so in the database would be a field called 'My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value'
and I will place my array values there the exact same way I would place them in the array with javascript - so the string would look like this:

"Saab","Volvo","BMW"

Now I get the string value using MySQL and echo the value using PHP, like this

```
<script>

    var myCarsArray = [<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>];

    alert("The second element in my array = "+myCarsArray[1]);

</script>
```

This alerts 'The second element in my array = S' !? It's treating the whole string as an array.

So the only way I could get this to work was to use 'eval'  this way :

```
<script>

   var myCarsArray = eval("["+<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>+"]");

   alert("The second element in my array = "+myCarsArray[1]);

</script>
```

This alerts correctly 'The second element in my array = Volvo'.

---

My question is: How do I save the string to the database so that I can just insert it into the javascript array as is, using:

```
myCarsArray = [<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>];
```

?

WITHOUT using a loop of any kind - I understand how to achieve this with a loop - I don't want to use a loop. Or is the 'eval' method the only way?

---

Clarification:

The question on this post is how to save javascript usable array values - as a string to MySQL - that can later be easily inserted into an array via -

```
myCarsArray = [<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>];
```

method.

AND Can this be done without using loops or the 'eval' statement?

Thanks in advance - I look forward to your replies.

Regards,
Ken

Comment: What does viewing the source of your first PHP example give?

Comment: do not add all words your know as tags, please

Comment: Eric - it shows:
var myCarsArray = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];

Comment: Thats an associative array with arrays inside, not a multidimensional array.

Comment: where are your `[` and `]` in `myCarsArray:"'Saab','Volvo",'BMW'"` ? It is just a string

Comment: @shhac +1 and why there is " instead of ' after Volvo

Comment: Actually it is first in a multidimensional array first, like this: MultiDimeArray = { SomeOtherValues:"SomeValue", myCarsArray:"'Saab','Volvo','BMW'" }; I just didn't want to over complicate the question. The values are still being populated in the multidimensional with the PHP the same way as the above example: MultiDimeArray = { SomeOtherValues:"SomeValue", myCarsArray:"<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>" };

Comment: myCarsArray:"<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>" if you try [] do you have  myCarsArray:"[<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>]" a code like this or  myCarsArray:[<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>] (with no " before/after [])?

Comment: Yeah ok, a _multidimensional array_ is an **array of arrays** (and so on), not an **object** that happens to have **arrays inside**. Can you index `MultiDimeArray[1]`, no - because it's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

My PHP syntax is a touch rusty, but you should be able to say something like:

```
<php
  <script>
  echo "var array = " . json_encode($My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value) . ";";
  </script>
?>
```

Comment: If I am reading his question correctly, he has a PHP array he wants as a Javascript array without going through a manual loop.   If that reading is right, then I'm suggesting replacing his existing code with the `json_encode`.

Comment: He is taking it from database. As a string. Your example will work if he is placing it into database, not taking from there

Answer (score 0):

```
MultiDimeArray = { SomeOtherValues:"SomeValue", 
                   myCarsArray:"<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>" 
                 };
```

Suppose it should be

```
MultiDimeArray = { SomeOtherValues:"SomeValue", 
                   myCarsArray:[<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>] 
                 };
```

In your output:
myCarsArray: **"** 'Saab','Volvo",'BMW' **"** instead of myCarsArray:**[**'Saab','Volvo",'BMW'**]**

Comment: I tried that just a minute ago and it did not work.
Did you test this answer and it worked for you?

Comment: @kdawg You have posted an output which will not work for sure. Did you check if you have no excess " or ' around [...]? Or inside... Besides, after your Volvo there " instead of '. Have you checked your console after you tried  myCarsArray:[<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>]?

Comment: @kdawg I've tested this in console: MultiDimeArray = { SomeOtherValues:"SomeValue", myCarsArray:['Saab','Volvo','BMW'] }; and it works. I'm lazy to turn on PHP now) But if you posted the same output as you you see it browser than there is mistake in 'Volvo*"* for sure. And this is a string:"'Saab','Volvo','BMW'", not an array. I see no any reason why it should not work.

Comment: @kdawg than maybe you should post a code as it is? and value of that variable_with_very_long_name. Because that looks really strange. It should work.

Comment: Yes - I see what you mean :" 'Saab','Volvo",'BMW' " - 
should be :" 'Saab','Volvo','BMW' " it was just a type-O as I tried to provide a multidimensional array example. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

But - yes - the array is a string - that is what I am trying to do - save the string as it would be in an array - and save that string to the database - then pull it out of the database as a string and convert it to one array.

Comment: I didn't want to post the multidimensional example - because it just over complicates it.

The simple javascript array example I posted - is what I am looking for an answer to.

Sorry if I caused any confusion with the type-O in my multidimensional array example reply.

Comment: @kdawg I understand what do you want to get. But maybe it would be better just copy/past code/output you have? With []. Because your code in question is ok. But at the same time it looks like you have something like this: `myCarsArray:"[<?php echo $My_Cars_Array_Database_String_Value; ?>]". You can simply post copy/pasted part of related code. And throw out everything not important

Comment: Your example works - but I still have to use 'eval' at the other end. I am trying to see if this can be done without using 'eval' cuz everyone says it is sooo evil.

Comment: Oh! Just post, at least, copy/pasted output! If you want to get some help. That your, as I understand, simplified and synthetic code works. So - you have something with database values/code not seen in code you provide us

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to complicate things with loops? They are basic and effective flow control tools, how complicated have you made it for yourself already by trying to use eval trickery?

Eval is evil, avoid it. You are trying to evaluate JavaScript from a server and you have no idea what it will do.

Be explicit in what you're trying to do, it will not only make maintenance easier in the future, nut if someone else inherits your work they won't want to hunt you down and do bad things to you for making their job a nightmare.

Comment: LOL - evil eval Why do people say eval is evil?
Give me one decisive reason why eval is evil?

Or do you just like to sing it... I mean say it because it rimes : )?

Comment: But overall - I disagree with your comments about saving the array value in its entirety is 'making it more difficult'

Pulling one value out of the database and inserting it in one action - is way more elegant than using another loop - if you are looping to create the data - and looping to unravel it - that is a lot of looping.

I say it is faster and way easier to understand and way more elegant to save the array as is.

Comment: And as well... I did not say "I don't want to complicate things with loops" - I said " I just didn't want to over complicate the question." 
- a loop is not complicated.

Comment: Any time I can pull something out of the database and use it exactly as it is - I'm going to do that. Over all it is much faster and is way more clear.

Comment: 1. It's evil because it's executing code that could well be malicious. 2. I didn't say anything about saving an array. 3. You should be encoding your data to **JSON** _before_ you send it out to the client, since that is it's natively handled data format.

Comment: 2 I did say something about saving arrays - that is what this entire post is about.
3 Can you give me an example of what you are saying here -I'm not sure.